# Highcharts with external CSV $.get - No xAxis date

Tags: csv, highcharts

I'm trying to create a spline chart using this CSV:

```
slave_id,date,time,rtc_temp,temp1,temp2,temp3
1,2017/12/26,16:42:59,21,11.50,13.13,5.88
2,2017/12/26,16:43:29,21,14.13,20.63,99.99
1,2017/12/26,16:44:00,21,11.50,13.13,5.88
2,2017/12/26,16:44:30,21,14.13,20.63,99.99
1,2017/12/26,16:45:01,21,11.50,13.13,5.88
2,2017/12/26,16:45:31,21,14.13,20.63,99.99
1,2017/12/26,16:46:02,21,11.50,13.13,5.88
2,2017/12/26,16:46:32,21,14.13,20.63,99.99
```

As you can see [here [IMAGE]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8unPZ.jpg), the graph is showing the date and time, but the x Axis is not accepting the date / time.

Ive tried using date.UTC, but that did not work either. Can someone point me in the right direction?

https://jsfiddle.net/asvoy6b9/ [not working due to CSV missing]

[Full code [Hastebin]](https://hastebin.com/ubocelegiv.xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that `date` variable in your code is a string:

```
            // all data lines start with a double quote
            line = line.split(',');
            date = line[1] + " " + line[2];

            (...)

                RTC.push([
                    date,
                    parseInt(line[3], 10)
                ]);
```

If you choose to construct the point's options as an array of two values and the first value is a string then it's treated as its `name` property (not `x`).

**Explanation**: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

In that case Highcharts assigns subsequent integers as x values for all points (that's why there're values like `00:00:00.000` (1 Jan 1970), `00:00:00.001` etc.).

You need to parse your date to timestamp. You can use `Date.UTC()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) or some other function for this.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working with `Date.UTC` using the following code:

```
var yyyymmdd = line[2].split("-"); //Split the date: 2017 12 16
var hhmmss = line[3].split(":"); //Split the time: 16 11 14
var date = Date.UTC(yyyymmdd[0], yyyymmdd[1] - 1, yyyymmdd[2], hhmmss[0], hhmmss[1], hhmmss[2]); //Stitch 'em together using Date.UTC
```